# Riddle about gingers

Tags: riddle, geography

> A kingdom and republic on my land do share a border;
>   my name contains an N, an R, and E (not in that order).
>
> An island world-renowned for having many natural wonders,
>   I am home to gingers, though in ever smaller numbers.
>
> You may think this riddle is so easy that it's scary,
>   but actually I am located far from Tipperary.

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are

> Borneo

A kingdom and republic on my land do share a border

> The island is politically divided among three countries: the kingdoms, Brunei and Malaysia in the north, and the republic Indonesia in the south. Malaysia and Indonesia share a border.

My name contains N, R and E

> Bo**rne**o

An island of natural wonders

> It has for example one of the oldest rainforests in the world.

I am home to gingers though in ever smaller numbers

> The orangutan population has plummeted this century due to human activities.

You may think this riddle is easy - but I am far from Tipperary

> I observe gingers in Ireland are flourishing, and indeed from Borneo it's a long way to Tipperary.

Comment: The same thing applies to Ireland

Comment: The "a long way to Tipperary" seems to be a clear hint that Ireland is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is-

> Ireland

Because:

> republic of Ireland shares a border with united kingdom (specifically northern Ireland) , has the letters N,R,E, it is an island nation, it is also the country with highest percentage of red heads(gingers), finally Tipperary is a town in Ireland

Comment: Surely Ireland is not located "far from Tipperary"?

Comment: Indeed, this fits everything except the last line. What a coincidence ;)

Answer (score 0):

I want to try with

> Republic of India

A kingdom and republic on my land do share a border;

> Bhutan is a monarchy, but there were also the kingdow of Britain for a long time.

my name contains an N, an R, and E (not in that order).

> **Re**public of I**n**dia

An island world-renowned for having many natural wonders,

> India used to be an Island, and there is the Himalaya as a border.

I am home to gingers, though in ever smaller numbers.

> The ginger (spice) is from India

You may think this riddle is so easy that it's scary,
but actually I am located far from Tipperary.

> India is far from Ireland.

Comment: Pretty good fit for most of the clues, although one couldn't really use the word "island" for this anymore, right?